# how to pass string number with leading zeros as string in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have id as string. for e.g. 001, 002, etc.
while rendering page I pass id simply, but at client side I receive number for e.g. 1, 2, etc.

```js
res.render('leafletDemo',{id:userID,latitude:latitude,longitude:longitude});
```

I want id as a string itself at client side.

Comment: What templating engine? What does the template do with the value?

Comment: template engine is ejs, and have to use id for database query purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have something like this in your template to transfer a variable from server-side code to client-side code:

```
<script>
  var id = <%= id %>;
  ...
</script>
```

If `id` is `"001"`, this renders to:

```
<script>
  var id = 001;
  ...
</script>
```

Which makes the client-side version of `id` a number.

For `id` to remain a properly formatted string, you can use this instead:

```
var id = <%- JSON.stringify(id) %>;
```

(note that it's using a hyphen, not an equal-sign, after `<%`; this means that the outcome of `JSON.stringify()` shouldn't be HTML-encoded by EJS)

This renders to:

```
var id = "001";
```

Which is what you want.

There's a slight security concern with this method, as it will allow [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) *if* `userId` can be inserted from the client side somehow. If it's just a database id, it'll most likely be alright.